# Current loop Converter

Tags: current, rs232, wire-loop

Is it possible to convert a 2 wires current loop to RS232, and from RS232 to current loop,
I am trying to put an RS232 sniffer in the middle so I can see what they are communicating to each other.

I measured the current, and it looks fluctuating between 44.0mA and 44.9mA

Thanks

Comment: You probably measured the average DC current in the current loop and that says nothing about the data being transmitted. How are you wishing to connect to the current loop? Direct wires or some magnetic thing?

Comment: I will be connected using direct wires.

Comment: Is the current loop transmission in fact RS485?

Comment: @Andyaka RS485 is not a current loop, It's a differential voltage. Or are you guessing that the OP is actually looking at RS485 and not a current loop?

Comment: @brhans No I was incorrect, I was having a late senior moment LOL! I was trying to ascertain if the transmission was differential (somehow!)

Comment: @Andyaka I am pretty sure it's current loop with 2 wires, the think is I am not sure if it's analog current loop or digital, and seems I can't find a converter from current loop with 2 wires to RS232.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of current loops- the old digital current loop which is serial, but they're seldom seen.

There is analog current loop- typically (but not always) 4~20mA DC. 10~50 and 1~5mA are also seen.

There is also analog-digital current loop with a base 4~20mA signal and a digital communication signal superimposed- eg [HART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_Addressable_Remote_Transducer_Protocol) (Highway Addressable Remote Transducer protocol).

If it's analog 4~20mA, just put an ammeter in series. 4mA = minimum scale, 20mA  = maximum scale.

If it's digital serial 4~20mA, you can put an optocoupler in series with some resistors to limit the LED current (and a diode across  the LED). You can then see the serial signal at the output. It's easier if you use a logic output optocoupler.

If it's HART, you can read the analog signal as above, for the digital you need a modem so it would be best to get ahold of a proper HART interface.

Comment: thanks @spehro-pefhany for your answer, I am still confused here, cause it seems I can't find much information about a current loop using only 2 wires, all the current loops I have seen and all the converters in the market are for 4 wires current loop.

Comment: @Midimo They're actually quite common in process control applications. Such devices are called "loop powered" transducers, signal conditioners or transmitters. They derive their power from the current loop and modulate the current they draw to represent their output signal.

Comment: I know it's too much, but can you point me where I can buy/order one?

Comment: White paper [here](http://www.acromag.com/sites/default/files/Acromag_Intro_TwoWire_Transmitters_4_20mA_Current_Loop_904A.pdf) and datasheet from the same company [here](http://www.acromag.com/sites/default/files/ST133_Isolated_Thermocouple_Millivolt_Transmitter.pdf) That's a temperature sensor one, there are voltage, current etc.